# Guzzle6 streams doesn't give me the exact output

Tags: php, stream, guzzle

I have been trying to integrate guzzle into my app and I am having trouble with it. So, I get my response object from

```
$response = $client->post(.....);
```

The response of the endpoint is in JSON format. However, when I try to use it I get the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-store Pragma: no-cache 
{
   // JSON HERE
}
```

Because of that I can't just use:

```
$array = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

How, can I get rid of it showing my the response header in the output of body?

Comment: `$response->getBody()->getContents()` give you also the header?

Comment: What exact version of Guzzle are you using?

Comment: 6.0.1 I think the problem is in HHVM :/

Comment: WOW I am so stupid. I just realized that the server that I was getting the response from was outputting that value... Fixed the issue now.